# Viewing conents of apache camel seda queue

Tags: apache-camel

Is it possible to view the contents of a seda queue in apache camel?

Am trying to create a route and want to view the contents of seda queue that i have created.

Comment: use logging. Refer to http://camel.apache.org/log.html ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes SEDA component is also browsable: http://camel.apache.org/browse
So there is API in Java and JMX that allows you to view the queue and the Exchange(s) on the queues.

Comment: isn't browse an overkill, i think a processor would suffice or log component would suffice the needs.

Comment: He may want to view the content on the queue, and leaving the data as-is on the queue. If you route from the seda queue to a log endpoint then the data is removed from the queue.